# Android: application upgrade rather than new version

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an old Android application I developed using the Eclipse Android Plugin, and am attempting to convert it to the new Android Studio.  The automatic conversion was a miserable failure, so I converted it manually.

The issue is that now, when I run my new application, it launches as a new installation rather than replacing the old one.  My guess is there's an ID somewhere that I need to copy from my old install, but I am at a complete loss as to where to find that.

One thing that may be the source of the issue is that in the old Eclipse IDE you specified the package name for your code separate from the project name.  But in Android Studio, the package name is derived directly from the project name.  When I originally created the project I misspelled the package name, so the package and project names aren't the same. I already have my new version of the app running under the same name and (misspelled) package name of the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things that need to match with your old application:

1. The package name set in the manifest. This is probably your issue because it happily installed your new app without complaining about signing identities not matching. Note that in Android Studio, the package name in the manifest doesn't actually matter, because it's overwritten by whatever package name you have put in your *build.gradle* file.
2. The signing identity. To install over another copy of the same app, it needs to be signed with the same key. When running from your IDE, it is using a debug.keystore and it most likely doesn't match the old one from Eclipse. If you really need to continue from the old installation, you can find your old debug.keystore that Eclipse was using and copy it into your new project. Modify *build.gradle* to point to this other debug.keystore.

Comment: Your recommendation #1 was close, I figured it out shortly after posting the question (after fighting with it for hours).  It was the "applicationID" set in build.gradle.  It was set as the non-misspelled version of the package name.

#2 is not an issue, since this is still in development.  I haven't signed an APK to send to the Google Store.

Comment: Ah yes, I think they recently changed `applicationName` to `applicationID` in a recent update to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If changing a package name is your problem it can be easily fixed.

You can perform a refactor on your package name from inside Android Studio (or change the folder name manually and update references).

Then you must check for your applicationId in your release (and debug if needed) configuration found in your **build.gradle** file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did try that to get most of the occurrences, but it didn't find them all.  I solved it, see comment above for the solution.